# Nuxt.js Client-Side Only Component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, plotly.js

I'm using [plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/) in my Nuxt.js project, and I kept receiving an error, saying `document not defined`, when plotly.js was imported. Nuxt.js documentation doesn't provide clear instruction on how one can make a component load and generate client-side only.

Comment: Although there are a couple of similar questions, none of them give the entire solution, only pieces that only when put together, would solve the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To overcome this issue, the component you're using must be placed inside the `client-only` environment:

```
<client-only>
    <component ...></component>
</client-only>
```

Furthermore, you need to store the component's `.vue` file somewhere other than the `components` directory that Nuxt.js automatically creates, because, during the build process, Nuxt.js automatically collects all of these files in order to bundle them, which will invoke the `import` for plotly.js inside the component. I created a directory called `components-lazy` and placed the component there.

Finally, you have to lazy-import the component in the page, layout or parent component, you're intending to use it in. I used the following syntax for this task:

```
export default {
    ...
    components: {
        Plotly: () => import('@/components-lazy/Plotly'),
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This will ensure that this particular component is only imported and rendered client-side.